# How to realize a nested tree in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am just getting started with Neo4j and Graph Databases and was wondering if nested hierarchical trees are a good use case for Neo4j. A common example would be a nested set of comments. For example:

```
 - Article
  - Comment 1 on Article
     - Comment 2 on Comment 1
     - Comment 3 on Comment 1
         - Comment 4 on Comment 3
  - Comment 5 on Article
```

As I understand it, the article and the comments would each be nodes. And each comment would have a parent-child relationship. Getting all direct comments on the article (1 and 5) would be easy. But how about retrieving the whole set?

Please excuse the use of layman terms. I figured it is better this way then trying to use the appropriate words while confusing everyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, because [trees actually are graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29) using a graph database to store a tree seems entirely appropriate to me.  What will perform the best will depend on your data access patterns, but basically trees are just a specialization of graphs.

Yes, in your case the "elements in the tree" would be nodes, and the "nesting" would be relationships.   So here's how you might mock up your example:

```
CREATE (root:Article {label: "Article"}),
       (c1:Comment {label: "Comment 1"}),
       (c1a:Comment {label: "Comment 2 on comment 1"}),
       (c1b:Comment {label: "Comment 3 on comment 1"}),
       (c1b1:Comment {label: "Comment 4 on comment 3"}),
       (c2:Comment {label: "Comment 5 on article"}),
       (root)<-[:reply]-(c1),
       (c1)<-[:reply]-(c1a),
       (c1)<-[:reply]-(c1b),
       (c1b)<-[:reply]-(c1b1),
       (root)<-[:reply]-(c2);
```

This just creates a bunch of nodes and relationships, mimicking the structure you provided.   Here I've chosen to always use `:reply` to connect things.

Now, "getting everything" just means traversing all of the `:reply` relationships we created:

```
MATCH p=(a:Article {label: "Article"})<-[:reply*1..]-(otherThing) 
WITH nodes(p) as nodes
RETURN nodes[length(nodes)-2] as InResponseTo, 
       nodes[length(nodes)-1] as CommentOrReply;
```

What this query does is traverse any number of `:reply` links (starting from the root "Article").  Then it only looks at the nodes in that path, and returns the last item (`CommentOrReply`) and what it was in response to (the second last item).

The result looks like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| InResponseTo                             | CommentOrReply                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Node[18]{label:"Article"}                | Node[19]{label:"Comment 1"}              |
| Node[19]{label:"Comment 1"}              | Node[20]{label:"Comment 2 on comment 1"} |
| Node[19]{label:"Comment 1"}              | Node[21]{label:"Comment 3 on comment 1"} |
| Node[21]{label:"Comment 3 on comment 1"} | Node[22]{label:"Comment 4 on comment 3"} |
| Node[18]{label:"Article"}                | Node[23]{label:"Comment 5 on article"}   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So that's how you traverse an entire tree.

**EDIT** - for what it's worth, "variable length path matching", which in the query above was just this bit:  `<-[:reply*1..]-` is for me one of the top 3 selling points for a graph database.  It's precisely that which graph DBs make really easy, that most of your other alternatives like relational make into a tortuously painful exercise.   So if you need to do that sort of thing (like here, assembling an entire tree) I would claim that argues for a graph DB because you're using it in its area of fundamental strength.

Comment: If you want to see some more use-cases for trees, check these out: http://jexp.de/blog/2014/04/importing-forests-into-neo4j/ and http://blog.bruggen.com/search?q=hierarchy

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great and detailled answer! I am trying to figure out at the moment how I could retrieve a nested hash, for example in JSON, from this result. But that isn't really a database question... In general everything looks so much faster than the nested set approach you have to come up with when using MySQL.

Comment: Yes; in mysql the common pattern is to have just one table for nodes that joins to itself - checking depth between 3-4 then becomes very hard.

Comment: Btw if you don't need a further reference of a node in a MATCH clause you can just use () instead of (otherThing). Just learned that.

Comment: Just a note for people who don't have a distinct label for their root node, the root node can be bound to the actual root with `WHERE NOT ()-->(a)`

Answer (score -1):

If the nested trees are entirely directed graphs and have no cycles (i.e., directed acyclical graph=DAG), then you might consider transitive closure methods in a relational database.  These allow very quick queries thru multiple nesting levels & finds of multiple intersections.  They have the n-squared issue, so there are lots of rows, but with bigint indexes the queries run fast.