# Query for a tree avoiding redundancy

Tags: neo4j, tree, cypher

I've build an example tree:

```
  CREATE (c1:treeCategory {name:"root", catID:1})
  CREATE (c2:treeCategory {name:"Maschinen", catID:2})      
  CREATE (c3:treeCategory {name:"Siebe", catID:3}) 
  CREATE (c4:treeCategory {name:"Zubehör", catID:4})       
  CREATE (c5:treeCategory {name:"SUPERTAUT", catID:5}) 
  CREATE (c6:treeCategory {name:"Fusion", catID:6}) 
  CREATE (c7:treeCategory {name:"Motor", catID:7}) 
  CREATE (c8:treeCategory {name:"Rahmen", catID:8}) 
  CREATE (c9:treeCategory {name:"SonoWave", catID:9})       
  CREATE (c10:treeCategory {name:"Scalper", catID:10})       
  CREATE (c11:treeCategory {name:"Rundsieb", catID:11})               
  CREATE (c12:treeCategory {name:"Dom", catID:12})  
  CREATE (c13:treeCategory {name:"FlowThru", catID:13})  
  CREATE (c2) -[:IS_SUBCATEGORY_OF]-> (c1)
  CREATE (c3) -[:IS_SUBCATEGORY_OF]-> (c1)      
  CREATE (c4) -[:IS_SUBCATEGORY_OF]-> (c1)      
  CREATE (c5) -[:IS_SUBCATEGORY_OF]-> (c3)      
  CREATE (c6) -[:IS_SUBCATEGORY_OF]-> (c3)
  CREATE (c7) -[:IS_SUBCATEGORY_OF]-> (c4)      
  CREATE (c8) -[:IS_SUBCATEGORY_OF]-> (c2)      
  CREATE (c9) -[:IS_SUBCATEGORY_OF]-> (c4)      
  CREATE (c10) -[:IS_SUBCATEGORY_OF]-> (c2)      
  CREATE (c11) -[:IS_SUBCATEGORY_OF]-> (c2)
  CREATE (c12) -[:IS_SUBCATEGORY_OF]-> (c8)
  CREATE (c13) -[:IS_SUBCATEGORY_OF]-> (c8)
```

In order to build the tree in PHP I need to read the graph and drop it into an array. The array shall be structured like

[image]

So I come up with a query like:

```
MATCH p=(a:treeCategory)<-[:IS_SUBCATEGORY_OF*1..]-() 
WITH nodes(p) as nodes
RETURN nodes[size(nodes)-2] as Parent, 
       nodes[size(nodes)-1] as Child;
```

Unfortunately I get most of data pairs redundant. The first column of the table may have redundant names as e.g. Maschinen has several subnodes. But the second column should have each node only once, so no catID shall be there twice or more often. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a variable-length pattern here, it should be enough to match just to just match to each pair of parent and child.

```
MATCH (parent:treeCategory)<-[:IS_SUBCATEGORY_OF]-(child) 
RETURN parent, child
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. The query returns all pairs - so far so good :) The idea was to receive also the structure of the graph (see table above) - this means to have an order which follows the graph, e.g. root -> Zubehör, Zubehör -> SonoWave, Zubehör -> Motor then as there is no other node below Zubehör the next node from root follows: root - > Siebe, Siebe -> Fusion a.s.o. to have the graph in a table sorted by the paths to build the tree afterwards in PHP based on the table. Any chance to change the quer to receive a copy of the graph and it paths as I need the relations?

Comment: I do not understand why first it works down until the "maschinen" nodes where I sudden receive doubles. As a hint I was trying to follow the example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258915/how-to-realize-a-nested-tree-in-neo4j

Comment: Take a look at your query results again, and see what it's looking at: `MATCH p=(a:treeCategory)<-[:IS_SUBCATEGORY_OF*1..]-() 
WITH nodes(p) as nodes
RETURN nodes, nodes[size(nodes)-2] as Parent, 
       nodes[size(nodes)-1] as Child;`

Comment: Sometimes the obvious isnt obvious to all ... I am not sure how to understand your hint? Sorry, but maybe you can give a nudge? Thanks

Comment: @Balael The root node (a) isn't locked to a particular node. In the example, their root node had a distinct label, so didn't have to check. In your case, you are getting the sum of all results for each possible starting "root" node. You can use `WHERE NOT ()-->(a)` to lock 'a' down as the actual tree root. Although I would sort the pairs on distance from the root (breath first vs depth first). That would give you a more reliable promise of return order. Otherwise, I wouldn't trust that the returned pairs are in any particular order.

Comment: Thank you very much Tezra.I am a beginner with Cypher - would it be possible to get a query example from you to understand it better? That would be awesome.